# Asymptotic for primitive Dirichlet characters over primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, characters, dirichlet-series

The Polya-Vinogradov's inequality states that if $\chi$ is a primitive character mod $q$ then $|\sum_{n\le x}\chi(n)|\le \sqrt{q}\log q$. I now want to give the estimation for the sum over primes, i.e. $\sum_{p\le x}\chi(p)$ and wonder if we can apply the Polya-Vinogradov's method?

It is proved in the book of H. Iwaniec and E. Kowalski (Corollary 5.29) that $\sum_{p\le x}\chi(p)<< \sqrt{q}x(\log x)^{-A}$ for any $A>0$ but the proof is somewhat complicated. Can we have the simpler proof for this fact?

Comment: That $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$ and for every non-principal $\chi \bmod q$ : $\sum_{p \le x} \chi(p)= o( \frac{x}{\ln x})$ is the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions $\bmod q$. So what do you mean with "a simpler proof", what did you show already, and what do you want to do ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for the asymptotic formula of $\sum_{n\le x}\mu(n)\chi(n)$ (Ex. 5, Montgomery-Vaughan's book). I am not familiar with the book of H. Iwaniec and E. Kowalski, and the proof of (5.29) is complicated for me. So, I just want to ask if there is another method to understand how the proof works.

Comment: Not really. For $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}$ it is the same as for $\zeta(s)$, you need to show the zero-free region $\sigma > 1-\frac{A}{\log |t|+B}$ with a bound $L,L',\frac{1}{L} = \mathcal{O}(\log^m |t|)$ in this region, use the [Perron formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron's_formula) $\sum_{n < x} \mu(n) \chi(n) = \frac{1}{2i \pi}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+ i\sigma} \frac{1}{ L(s,\chi)} \frac{x^s}{s} ds$, shift the contour to the boundary of the zero-free region, and estimate what you get.

Comment: Could you please explain more, or give reference about the formula you mentioned in the first comment: $\sum_{p\le x}\chi(p)=o(\frac{x}{\log x})$?

Comment: The reference is your book. What do you not understand ? Did you prove the usual prime number theorem yet ?